# How do I format a date in a SQL Where clause?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a .NET 2010 app that bangs against a SQL db. On the app side, a user can search on Begin date and End Date. Bot of these are just Month + Year. I then format them so they are complete dates. So when they go to the stored proc they'll look like this...

Begin Date: 1/1/2011 
End Date: 5/31/2011

But the date in the db is broken up into 3 int fields, Month,Day & Year, ...of which Day may or may not be filled in (0 if not). It would be ok for this to always default to one when running this query. So if the values in the db were Month=3, Day=0 Year=2011 I would like the sql statement to render as

Where FORMATTEDDATEHERE  between '1/1/2011' and '5/31/2011'

I just can't figure out how to format sql fields in a where clause.

Comment: What data types are your columns Month, Day and Year?

Answer (score 0):

you could build the date using datadd functions within the WHERE clause EG.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE DATEADD(Day, field_days-1, DATEADD(Month, field_months-1, DATEADD(Year, field_years-1900, 0))) BETWEEN '1/1/2011' AND '5/31/2011'
```

Just replace field_days, field_months, field_years with the int fields on the table for days, months and year.  This will return all records within the date range.

Is this what you require?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [c_year]) + '/' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), [c_month]) + '/' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), [c_day])) 
BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/5/31'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: When I do this I get the following ..."The multi-part identifer FIELDHERE cound not be bound." I should mention this is a dynamic query.

Comment: Could you post the complete query?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CAST(Year AS varchar) + RIGHT(100 + Month, 2) +
      RIGHT(100 + COALESCE(NULLIF(Day, 0), 1), 2) BETWEEN ...
```